# How to pass parameters to jQuery document.ready() function (ASP.NET MVC, C#)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to pass a parameter to the jQuery **document.ready() function** from my View:

```
$(document).ready(function (parameter){
        $('select[name=Product]').val(parameter);
});
```

How can I fire the event from my View and pass the parameter? I use **Razor** as View engine.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't. The document.ready function doesn't take parameters. You could for example define this parameter as a global variable in your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

and then in your separate javascript file use this global variable:

```
$(function() {
    $('select[name=Product]').val(model.SomeProperty);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I use a master page (_Layout) where I place the <head> and all the Javascript but I would like to restrict this behavior to a specific View.

Comment: @Francesco, in this case in your _Layout you could define a `Scripts` section which you could override in the specific view and which will contain the definition of the global javascript variable.

Comment: I used this implementation, but without the `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode())` part.

Answer (score 21):

To avoid using global variables, you can define a closure and then returning this function to `ready()`:

```
function start(parameter)
{
    return function()
    {
        /*...use parameter */
        alert('parameter: ' + parameter);
    }
}
```

and then call `ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(start('someValue'));
```

You can also define the start function in a external .js file and calling ready (for example) in your main html file.
Example:
external script.js:

```
function start(parameter)
{
   return function()
   {
        /*...use parameter */
        alert('parameter: ' + parameter);
   }
}
```

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(start('someValue'));
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Calling `ready()` in the latter file allows you to pass server parameters to your functions. Example (using PHP. In this case you must change the extension from html to php to this file):

```
$(document).ready(start('<?php echo $serverParameter; ?>'));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can effectively accomplish this with a closure. That is, if you are calling something like `$(document).ready(startup)` then you can easily rewrite `startup` so that you can call it with a parameter, e.g. `$(document).ready(startup(7))`. Pablo gave an excellent underrated answer, and it is worth giving a more detailed example.

#### Example

Here is a page which displays an alert, invoked by `$(document).ready()`, that calculates `6*9`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function startup() {
        alert('6 * 9 = ' + 6 * 9);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    Hello!
    <script>
      $(document).ready(startup);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Say you want to replace "9" with a variable parameter. The 4-step recipe to do this is:

1. Parameterize the function.
2. Wrap the function body in a closure. That is, `return function() {...}`.
3. Parameterize the body.
4. Call the function with the parameter.

Applying this to the above code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function startup(x) { // Step 1 - Parameterize the function
        return function() { // Step 2 - Put body in "return function() {...}"
        alert('6 * '+x+' = ' + 6 * x); // Step 3 - Parameterize the body.
        } // (closing brace for step 2)
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    Hello!
    <script>
      $(document).ready(startup(7)); // Step 4 - Call function with parameter.
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This displays the alert "6 * 7 = 42".

#### What's Happening?

`$(document).ready()` takes as its parameter a function. This is why it is called in the first version above with just `startup` as the parameter. In contrast if you called it with `startup()` you wouldn't be passing in the `startup` function anymore, you would be passing in the *return value* of `startup`.

Since `$(document).ready()` takes a function as its parameter, that's what we give it: `startup` is transformed in the second version above into a function that returns a function, which has the parameter `x` set to the value we pass it initially. That is, `startup(7)` returns a function to `$(document).ready()` that has the value of `x` set to `7`.

#### OP's Question

To specifically apply this to the OP's question, rewrite that call as

```
$(document).ready((function(x) { return function() {
    $('select[name=Product]').val(x);
}})('name'));
```

where `'name'` can be any other value that gets substituted for `x`. No need for global variables.

More information: [JavaScript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Comment: What I don't get is why you need steps 2 and 3. Steps 1 and 4 (parameterize and call with that parameter) would suffice, wouldn't they? You have the 'startup' function scope to hide your vars and everything inside. Why is the extra function needed?

Comment: According to that "JavaScript closures" question you pointed to, "In JavaScript, if you declare a function within another function, then the local variables of the outer function can remain accessible after returning from it." So it's a way to have private access to them.

Comment: If you only did steps 1 and 4, what would `startup(7)` return? Answer: nothing. This is why you need steps 2 and 3 to return a function. `$(document).ready(f)` doesn't immediately execute `f`. It calls `f()` once the document is ready. You need to pass it a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply echo your parameter value into the Javascript code if its inline in your view.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $('select[name=Product]').val('@ViewBag.Parameter');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I never use the ViewBag because I cannot test its behavior

Comment: ViewBag was only an example. Of course this will work with Model properties too.