# why is anonymous function input parameter not recognized by ajax call inside

Tags: javascript, ajax

Why does the "action" input parameter not recognized by the ajax call?
My code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function (string action) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: @Url.Action(action, "Default") ,
                        data: param = "",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: successFunc,
                        error: errorFunc
                    }).done(function () {
                        alert("Success");
                    }).error(function () {
                        alert("Faile");
                    });
                }
            </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Most likely because serverside code is evaluated at render time... and not sure where you learned `(string action)`

Comment: You can't pass parameters to  $(document).ready(), please see this related post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976938/how-to-pass-parameters-to-jquery-document-ready-function-asp-net-mvc-c)

Comment: ah! Want to enter this as an answer, Ryan, so I can accept it?

Comment: @SuLlewellyn Removed as the haters began hating.

Comment: There's a whole lot of mixing languages happening in your code here.  Specifying a `string` type in JavaScript, trying to use a JavaScript variable in C#...  While it's talking about different languages, you'd really do well to read and understand the concepts presented in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: Since mplungjan found this question to be a duplicate, I can't accept Ryan's answer. My apologies to Ryan

Comment: @David - you are right - I ended up ripping out my code and starting over. The problem turned out to be one of Javascript scope -- I noticed that when I placed my ajax call inside the script associated with the command link the user would click, then my call would be activated.